# compilation error in c struct variable assignment

Tags: c, struct, variable-assignment

Got a doubt in `struct` variable assignment.

```
struct udata
{
    char name[50];
    int num;
    char ch;
};

void main()
{
    struct udata a = {"ram", 20, 'a'};
    struct udata b;
    //b = {"ashok", 10, 'c'}; - illegal
    b = a;
}
```

In above code `b = {"ashok", 10, 'c'};` is giving compilation error but its accepting `b = a;`. I hope both are similar kind of assignment, but I dont know why its not accepting first one. Can someone explain me why it is so ?

Note : I am compiling in a fedora gcc compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do cannot be done directly in standard C. The best standard and portable solution is to use a temporary:

```
const struct udata tmp = {"ashok", 10, 'c'};
b = tmp;
```

However, in practice, the following is often (but not always!) allowed by compilers (*note below):

```
b = (struct udata){...};
```

(* **note:** I believe at least MSVC does not support this syntax, and probably many others; but just throwing it out there. GCC, however, *does* support it)

Answer (score 4):

Initializers can only be used at declaration time. If you want to initialize `b` after declaration, then you can do it by using a compound literal-- a C99 feature:

```
b =  (struct udata){"ashok", 10, 'c'};
```

GCC also support copound literals as an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html).

Answer (score 2):

That's how C is designed and specified to work. There's nothing you can do. If you have a structure variable, you can only initialize it by an initializer in the declaration or by later initializing the individual members.

---

In the future, when posting a question regarding compiler errors, please include the complete and unedited error log in the question.